# Installing Azure 1.8 SDK via WebpiCmd

Tags: azure, web-platform-installer

I'm trying to install the Azure 1.8 SDK for Visual Studio 2012 via webpicmd.exe as shown on the SDK download page: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35448

The command I'm trying to run is

```
webpicmd /install /products:WindowsAzureToolsVS2012_1_8 /accepteula
```

When I do so I get the message

```
The following products are not available on this machine or already installed: WindowsAzureToolsVS2012_1_8
```

If I use the Web Platform Installer GUI I am able to install the SDK but I'd like to be able to automate it. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the IDs that work for azure sdk 1.8 and 2.0 currently.

The 1.8 id is `/products:VWDOrVs11AzurePack_1_8_1`

The 2.0 id is `/products:vwdorvs11azurepack`

Both of those worked for me using the latest web platform installer.

Answer (score 1):

The command closest to what you are probably looking for is this:

`webpicmd /Install /Products:WindowsAzureToolsVS2012 /AcceptEula /Log:log.txt`

However you say that you want 1.8 SDK, but the command will install Visual Studio tools, not SDK and v1.8 is latest, so in future you might get higher version. From what I know and what I tried, there is currently no way of explicitly choosing version 1.8 for VS2012.

Comment: Is the SDK not a dependency of the Azure tools? I would expect it to be automatically installed when installing the tools.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the latest version of the web platform installer? Or is the correct version of webpicmd.exe being used when you run the command.

I just ran into this problem and found it was because I installed an older version of webpicmd.exe

Comment: I'm installing web platform installer via Chocolatey. It's possible that it is installing an old version, I'll check that.